# Unable to complete install: 'unsupported configuration: emulator '/usr/lib/xen-4.11/bin/qemu-system-i386' not found'

Tags: qemu, xen, hyper-v

#### Log:

```
Unable to complete install: 'unsupported configuration: emulator '/usr/lib/xen-4.11/bin/qemu-system-i386' not found'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2119, in _do_async_install
    guest.installer_instance.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 419, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 362, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3732, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: emulator '/usr/lib/xen-4.11/bin/qemu-system-i386' not found
```

---

#### Details

**Hypervisor**: Xen

**Virtualized OS**: [Windows](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/) (developer [HyperV](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Linux_support) Image on external drive)

**Host OS**: Debian

**Manager**: [`virt-manager`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/virt-manager)

**Installed Package**: `apt-get install xen-system` (have since rebooted)

**Host Hardware**: x230 ThinkPad with BIOS virtualization settings turned to enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=830307) in debian libvirt. The workaround is as follows:

```
cd /usr/lib/xen-4.11/bin/
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/qemu-system-i386 qemu-system-i386
```

(You must have package `qemu` installed)

Taken from [a similar bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1334554#c1) in Red Hat that has since been fixed.